# sessionStorage on firstOpenPage on Chrome - React

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

Please, can someone help?

Have created a simples react+vite code to exemplify. This is the App.tsx, the rest is default.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css'

function App() {
    localStorage.setItem("hi1", '1');
    sessionStorage.setItem("hi2", '2');

  return (
    <>
      <p>hi</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

When i first open de page, the localStoraged is saved, but the sessionStorage is not (pressing F12 to check).

Only after reload the page, F5, is that the sessionStorage is saved.

This only happens on Chrome (tested up to the latest version of it). Tried on Firefox and Edge, and on both saved on first load.

Any tips on how to make it work on Chrome? Or this only happens here?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use the `useEffect` hook like this:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("hi1", '1');
    sessionStorage.setItem("hi2", '2');
  }, []); // The empty array means this effect runs once on mount

  return (
    <>
      <p>hi</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the standard way to handle state change in functional components in React.

Comment: Yes. You're correct. But the result is the same in this case. And the sessionStorage still isnt saved in the first time.